# Connection to SQL(MySQL) server on gcloud from mobile network

Tags: google-cloud-sql, gcloud

I am trying to connect 3 beckhoff plc's to my MySQL database on gcloud.

1 plc is on our home network, the 2 other is on 2 different mobile sites, and are connected via mobile network(4g/3g)

The 1 plc connects with out any difficulty.

The 2 plc's that is connected via a mobile networks will not connect. They return with a timeout error.

I suspect that is because of how mobile networks work, that makes it, that i can not just add them to my "Authorized networks".

Is it just me and are the a way to connect to my MySQL server on gcloud?

Background:

I started a google cloud account yesterday to try it out. So this might just be a problem of me not understanding the service.

Comment: Your configuration is unclear and I'm unfamiliar with "Beckhoff PLCs" *but* I suspect your home network uses IPv4 and your mobile networks are using IPv6. It appears that you're permitting access from IPv4 addresses but not IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy), which uses service account credentials to authenticate connections to your database.

You could also manually configure an [SSL certificate](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance) and use that instead.